# .NET EF Core UpdateData based on other columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have table with columns:

| Id | Field | Operator | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "one" | "contains" | "o" |
| 2 | "two" | "contains" | "o" |

I want to merge columns "Field", "Operator", "Value" into one column "ConditionalsJSON" as JSON array of objects.

I know I can do it with SQL:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE [dbo].[TableName] SET ConditionalsJSON = '[{ \"Field\": ' + Field + ', \"Operator\": ' + Operator + ', \"Value\": ' + Value + ' }]'");
```

But can I do that with `.UpdateData()` method?
Something like:

```
migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
    table: "TableName",
    keyColumn: "Id",
    column: "ConditionalsJSON",
    value: "[{ \"Field\": " + Field + ", \"Operator\": " + Operator + ", \"Value\": " + Value + " }]");
```

Comment: Could it be that you are missing the `keyValue` property like: `keyValue: 1`?

Comment: @IceCode `keyValue: 1` it will update only for `Id=1` or for all records?

Comment: Ahh ok, I thought perhaps if you only had a few records you could manually write in the id´s, but I do see the issue if you have many records.

Answer (score 0):

For this to be possible a variant of `UpdateData` would be needed that accepts an Expression that can produce a new `value` using data from the old/existing entity. But [none of the `UpdateData` overloads has such a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.updatedata), it's just not designed for that.

Besides SQL (complicated / can break easily), an IMO good alternative that I use myself is to write an "UpdateItems" method that runs from the `Startup` method and that will use a `DbContext`. It can load all records that need updating, and then update them, see example below.

In this case I'm using [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to) to create the JSON because doing it manually is waiting for problems to occur e.g. with data that needs to be escaped or encoded.

```
var items = dbContext.Items.Where(x => x.ConditionalsJSON == null);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var obj = new { item.Field, item.Operator, item.Value };
    var array = new[] { obj };
    item.ConditionalsJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize(array);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

For simplicity this code is synchronous, of course you can also do it async. But since this runs at App startup, the overhead of using `async` may actually slow it down *and* ideally no other tasks should run on the database anyway while this is running.

Comment: In migrations there is no `dbContext`. Simple answer for this question is NO, SQL is needed.

Comment: Please read, that is why I am saying that this should run in the Startup method.

Comment: It is also bad idea. Migrations is a history. Renaming properties, dropping them will break this solution. Better SQL and do not invent another migration handler.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, it works for me. Not every data fix is simple to write in SQL, or it may not be apparent when the migration is created and rolled out, or it may not even be related to a migration. Renaming or dropping properties usually has many consequences, my IDE will let me know so I can update this in mere seconds or remove it if its work is done.